# Beamer theorem inside itemize

Tags: beamer

I would like to use \begin{theorem} \end{theorem} in an itemized list in beamer. Unfortunately, this messes up the indentation of the itemization, and pushes the item sign to the far left of the page - it seems that Theorem has a fixed position, and the item sign gets on the left of it. In other words, the theorem environment seems to define the layout instead of the itemization. Is there any way to change it?

I would also like to change the colour of how Theorem appears.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! To help the helpful people here help you, it would be useful if you could add a short, complete document showing the problem (a so-called Minimal Working Example, or [**MWE**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) to your question.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can wrap the theorem in a `minipage` of whatever width you'd like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \vspace*{-1.2\baselineskip}
        \begin{theorem}
            test
        \end{theorem}
    \end{minipage}
\item test 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple but efficient! :-) Thanks.

Comment: @user60121 You're welcome!